# Access Kafka data in instance variable from Flask endpoints

Tags: python, flask, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have written a Kafka consumer, in which I am capturing some metrics inside a class variable, below is the code of consumer.

```
class Consumer(Thread):

    def __init__(self, kafka_topic, kafka_brokers, group_id):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer(kafka_topic, bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers, group_id=group_id)
        self.metrics = Metrics()

    def process_message(self, message):
        msg_data = json.loads(message.value)
        meeting_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        metric_response = MetricResponse(meeting_id)

        #perform some task and update metric response object

        self.metrics.add_metric_response(metric_response)
        print('\nFinished......')

    def get_metrics(self):
        return self.metrics

    def run(self):
        print('Consumer started...')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            for message in self.consumer:
                executor.map(self.process_message, (message,))
```

Now i have written a flask api to retrieve this metrics variable where I am starting consumer also but I am getting empty metrics object.
Below is api code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
consumer = Consumer('my-topic', ['localhost:9092'], 'my-group')
consumer.start()

@app.route('/metrics')
def get_metrics():
    metrics = consumer.get_metrics()
    metrics_response = metrics.toJSON()
    return Response(metrics_response, 200, mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I need help to access metrics object from consumer class. I am new to Python

Comment: You don't show a toJSON function... Also `jsonify` is a Flask method that might be useful here

Comment: I have written toJSON function, that's not the issue, if i run consumer alone via main method then i am getting metrics object as expected

Comment: Why don't you consume from the topic during a GET request? How do you know messages are actively consumed on the server? Because I believe Flask is single threaded

Comment: It might be helpful to remove lines of code that are not the issue, this just helps us to efficiently read your code.

Comment: @Code every line of code in the question is used...

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to expose this api just to see some metrics, consumer is not dependent on api call